Как создать свои теги через XSLT
Есть xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Records count="2">
  <Metadata>
    <FieldDefinitions>
      <FieldDefinition id="123" guid="ef0ce125-ca87-4f13-92f6-988eefcb389e" name="Наименование1" alias="Наименование1" />
      <FieldDefinition id="456" guid="524f9b49-316e-4dd8-ae49-7a3e58b67adf" name="Наименование2" alias="Наименование2" />
      <FieldDefinition id="789" guid="62c6d1d3-8b49-4128-a758-ec383894c432" name="Наименование3" alias="Наименование3" />
    </FieldDefinitions>
  </Metadata>
  <LevelCounts>
    <LevelCount id="111" guid="ac53e54a-b5b3-4f92-aba1-b67e4156a868" count="2" />
  </LevelCounts>
  <Record contentId="253172" levelId="329" levelGuid="ad31d387-af1a-4642-9bbf-719f9b3ab251" moduleId="222" parentId="0">
    <Field id="123" guid="ef0ce125-ca87-4f13-92f6-988eefcb389e" type="6">1223445</Field>
    <Field id="456" guid="524f9b49-316e-4dd8-ae49-7a3e58b67adf" type="1">Имя чего нибудь</Field>
    <Field id="789" guid="62c6d1d3-8b49-4128-a758-ec383894c432" type="1">аааааааа</Field>
  </Record>
  <Record contentId="253195" levelId="329" levelGuid="ad31d387-af1a-4642-9bbf-719f9b3ab251" moduleId="222" parentId="0">
    <Field id="123" guid="ef0ce125-ca87-4f13-92f6-988eefcb389e" type="6">1233</Field>
    <Field id="456" guid="524f9b49-316e-4dd8-ae49-7a3e58b67adf" type="1">Имя чего нибудь2</Field>
    <Field id="789" guid="62c6d1d3-8b49-4128-a758-ec383894c432" type="1">бббббббббб</Field>
  </Record>
</Records>

Как преобразовать это в это?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Records>
   <Record>
      <id>1223445</id>
      <name>Имя чего нибудь</name>
      <comment>аааааааа</comment>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <id>1233</id>
      <name>Имя чего нибудь2</name>
      <comment>бббббббббб</comment>
   </Record>
</Records>

Я использую вот такой xslt:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/Records">
  <Records>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Record"/>
  </Records>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Record">
  <Record>
    <xsl:for-each select="Field">
      <xsl:element name="{/Records/Metadata/FieldDefinitions/FieldDefinition[@guid=current()/@guid]/@alias}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Record>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

мне нужно сделать собственные наименования полей, заполнить их по guid. Т.к. в системе могут измениться наименования, поэтому нужно сделать привязку по guid. Но guid использовать в качестве наименования нельзя(XSLT интерпретатор ругается на это).

Какой у вас процессор XSLT? Можете ли вы использовать XSLT 2.0 или более позднюю версию?

Вот решение на основе XSLT 2.0 или более поздней версии.
XSLT использует идею Lookup для присвоения желаемых имен XML-элементов.
Полезная ссылка для XSLT 3.0 для Python
Вы можете скачать Saxon Home Edition (HE) бесплатно.
Входной XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Records count="2">
    <Metadata>
        <FieldDefinitions>
            <FieldDefinition id="123"
                             guid="ef0ce125-ca87-4f13-92f6-988eefcb389e"
                             name="Наименование1" alias="Наименование1"/>
            <FieldDefinition id="456"
                             guid="524f9b49-316e-4dd8-ae49-7a3e58b67adf"
                             name="Наименование2" alias="Наименование2"/>
            <FieldDefinition id="789"
                             guid="62c6d1d3-8b49-4128-a758-ec383894c432"
                             name="Наименование3" alias="Наименование3"/>
        </FieldDefinitions>
    </Metadata>
    <LevelCounts>
        <LevelCount id="111" guid="ac53e54a-b5b3-4f92-aba1-b67e4156a868"
                    count="2"/>
    </LevelCounts>
    <Record contentId="253172" levelId="329"
            levelGuid="ad31d387-af1a-4642-9bbf-719f9b3ab251" moduleId="222"
            parentId="0">
        <Field id="123" guid="ef0ce125-ca87-4f13-92f6-988eefcb389e" type="6">1223445</Field>
        <Field id="456" guid="524f9b49-316e-4dd8-ae49-7a3e58b67adf" type="1">Имя чего нибудь</Field>
        <Field id="789" guid="62c6d1d3-8b49-4128-a758-ec383894c432" type="1">аааааааа</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="253195" levelId="329"
            levelGuid="ad31d387-af1a-4642-9bbf-719f9b3ab251" moduleId="222"
            parentId="0">
        <Field id="123" guid="ef0ce125-ca87-4f13-92f6-988eefcb389e" type="6">1233</Field>
        <Field id="456" guid="524f9b49-316e-4dd8-ae49-7a3e58b67adf" type="1">Имя чего нибудь2</Field>
        <Field id="789" guid="62c6d1d3-8b49-4128-a758-ec383894c432" type="1">бббббббббб</Field>
    </Record>
</Records>

XSLT 2.0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="lookup" match="row" use="@alias"/>

    <xsl:variable name="lookup">
        <row alias="Наименование1" elem="id"/>
        <row alias="Наименование2" elem="name"/>
        <row alias="Наименование3" elem="comment"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/Records">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Record">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Field">
                        <xsl:variable name="alias"
                                      select="/Records/Metadata/FieldDefinitions/FieldDefinition[@guid=current()/@guid]/@alias"/>
                        <xsl:element name="{key('lookup', $alias, $lookup)/@elem}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Результат
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<Records>
  <Record>
    <id>1223445</id>
    <name>Имя чего нибудь</name>
    <comment>аааааааа</comment>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <id>1233</id>
    <name>Имя чего нибудь2</name>
    <comment>бббббббббб</comment>
  </Record>
</Records>


Из предыдущего вопроса автора я предполагаю lxml, а в нём вроде только XSLT 1.0

Я добавил ссылку для загрузки XSLT 3.0 для Python

Спасибо за ответ. Это действительно работает, но в моём случае я всё же его изменил. Я поменял alias на guid. Это нужно чтобы привязаться к guid. Т.к. если во внешней системе кто-то поменяет наименование, то XSL перестанет работать.

Рад слышать, что предложенное решение с небольшими изменениями работает для вас. Пожалуйста, не забудьте пометить его как ответ.

Мой конечный результат получился таким:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="lookup" match="row" use="@guid"/>

    <xsl:variable name="lookup">
        <row guid="ef0ce125-ca87-4f13-92f6-988eefcb389e" elem="id"/>
        <row guid="524f9b49-316e-4dd8-ae49-7a3e58b67adf" elem="name"/>
        <row guid="62c6d1d3-8b49-4128-a758-ec383894c432" elem="comment"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/Records">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Record">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Field">
                        <xsl:variable name="guid"
                                      select="/Records/Metadata/FieldDefinitions/FieldDefinition[@guid=current()/@guid]/@guid"/>
                        <xsl:element name="{key('lookup', $guid, $lookup)/@elem}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

